# How to retrieve only the tabular data from a big text file using python

Tags: python

I have a big text file and it contains a tabular form data also
I want to retrieve the data from the tabular form starting with a header and till the end of table in the file(Don't know where the end may be after 20 or 30 lines, the header and end may vary for different files)
I should ignore all the text in the file ,just need that tabular form and put in a separate file.

Example:
brand and dominant market presence in the top life science clusters,
including Greater Boston, the Bay Area, Shoojhriwp,

### ------

```
  Header
Row1  val1 val2 val3
ROw2  val1 --   ---
row    ""   ""  ""
""     ""   "" """
""

(May be end of the table)

again the text........
.........................
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

So, how can I retrieve the data from the table(same tabular format as it is in the text file)  and put it in a file.

I have tried something and it is not working

Comment: How do you identify the table? Are there any specific markers surrounding the table that can be used to identify it?

Comment: Also, `I have tried something and it is not working` <- please edit your post to include your attempt

Answer (score 0):

So one thing you can do is read the file line by line and once you reach the header of a table (I'm assuming you know beforehand what the table header looks like) you can use the split method on it where you separate it on spaces (or maybe commas) and record this data. Assuming the data in the table follows a fixed structure where every row has the same number of columns once the number of results from split is different you can stop recording data from the file.

**Here is how you use the str.split() method**

Lets say you have a string

```
line = "col1 col2 col3"
column_list = line.split()
```

column_list is now ["col1", "col2", "col3"]

Since in this example there is only 3 elements in the list, what you can do is check the size of the list before you store the values from each line of the table. Once you have a list that has a size different from the previous rows you know you've reached the end of the table in the file

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be something like this (with Pandas installed)

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

f = open('path/to/file.txt', 'r')
fileobj = StringIO(f.read())
dataframe = pd.read_csv(fileobj, header=0,
                        sep='\t', engine="python")
```

Unless I see a more detailed example with proper formatting, it's hard to write code for it.